# Subtract date & time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsdate

I have two date-time strings, but how can I subtract them?
I tried to use the `-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]` method, but I can't get it to work.

I want the exact `hh:mm:ss` difference. If the situation is like this: my first time string is `2011/4/28 23:00:00`, and the second is `2011/4/29 1:00:00`, then the difference is 2 hours -- that's what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your strings to `NSDate` objects using `NSDateFormatter` (the method is `dateFromString`, I think). Then the difference in seconds is simply

```
[date1 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
```

Read up on date formatting topics in the dev docs to find the exact invocations of date formatters.